# Wicked pdf gem not creating correct data in pdf on rails production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using Wicked pdf gem for creating pdf. It is absolutely working fine on my local. But on production it is giving serious issues. The pdf is generated but in spite of generating a single page it generates 14-15 pages with data like this:

> ")),this.$.write(e),this.$.close()},find:function(e){return new CKEDITOR.dom.nodeList(this.$.querySelectorAll(e))},findOne:function(e){return(e=this.$.querySelector(e))?new CKEDITOR.dom.element(e):null},_getHtml5ShivFrag:function(){var e=this.getCustomData("html5ShivFrag");return e||
>       (e=this.$.createDocumentFragment(),CKEDITOR.tools.enableHtml5Elements(e,!0),this.setCustomData("html5ShivFrag",e)),e}}),CKEDITOR.dom.nodeList=function(e){this.$=e},CKEDITOR.dom.nodeList.prototype={count:function(){return this.$.length},getItem:function(e){return
>       0>e||e>=this.$.length?null:(e=this.$[e])?new CKEDITOR.dom.node(e):null}},CKEDITOR.dom.element=function(e,t){"string"==typeof e&&(e=(t?t.$:document).createElement(e)),CKEDITOR.dom.domObject.call(this,e)},CKEDITOR.dom.element.get=function(e){return(e="string"==typeof e?
>       document.getElementById(e)||document.getElementsByName(e)[0]:e)&&(e.$?e:new CKEDITOR.dom.element(e))},CKEDITOR.dom.element.prototype=new CKEDITOR.dom.node,CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml=function(e,t){var n=new CKEDITOR.dom.element("div",t);return
>       n.setHtml(e),n.getFirst().remove()},CKEDITOR.dom.element.setMarker=function(e,t,n,i){var
>       r=t.getCustomData("list_marker_id")||t.setCustomData("list_marker_id",CKEDITOR.tools.getNextNumber()).getCustomData("list_marker_id"),o=t.getCustomData("list_marker_names")||t.setCustomData("list_marker_names",{}).getCustomData("list_marker_names");return
>       e[r]=t,o[n]=1,t.setCustomData(n,i)},CKEDITOR.dom.element.clearAllMarkers=function(e){for(var t in e)CKEDITOR.dom.element.clearMarkers(e,e[t],1)},CKEDITOR.dom.element.clearMarkers=function(e,t,n){var
>       i,r=t.getCustomData("list_marker_names"),o=t.getCustomData("list_marker_id");for(i in r)t.removeCustomData(i);t.removeCustomData("list_marker_names"),n&&(t.removeCustomData("list_marker_id"),delete e[o])},function(){function e(e,t){return-1<(" "+e+" ").replace(o," ").indexOf(" "+t+"
>       ")}function t(e){var t=!0;return e.$.id||(e.$.id="cke_tmp_"+CKEDITOR.tools.getNextNumber(),t=!1),function(){t||e.removeAttribute("id")}}function n(e,t){var n=CKEDITOR.tools.escapeCss(e.$.id);return"#"+n+" "+t.split(/,\s*/).join(", #"+n+" ")}function i(e){for(var
>       t=0,n=0,i=a[e].length;i>n;n++)t+=parseInt(this.getComputedStyle(a[e][n])||0,10)||0;return t}var r=document.createElement("_").classList,r="undefined"!=typeof r&&null!==String(r.add).match(/[Native code]/gi),o=/[\n\t\r]/g;CKEDITOR.tools.extend(CKEDITOR.dom.element.prototype,
>       {type:CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT,addClass:r?function(e){return this.$.classList.add(e),this}:function(t){var n=this.$.className;return n&&(e(n,t)||(n+=" "+t)),this.$.className=n||t,this},removeClass:r?function(e){var t=this.$;retur

The entire 14-15 pages are like this.

This is the method that creates pdf.

```
def generate_supplier_commission_pdf
  @start_date = params[:start_date].to_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
  @end_date = params[:end_date].to_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')    
  if params[:sec_filter].present?
    sec_filter = true
  else
    sec_filter = false
  end

  results = get_report_results_by_type(params[:report_type], @start_date, @end_date, sec_filter)
  @results = JSON.parse(results)
  @type = params[:report_type].to_i

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render  pdf:  "report",
        layout:              'pdf_layout',
        template:            'reports/generate_supplier_commission_pdf.html.erb',
        encoding:            'UTF8',
        print_media_type:    true,
        disposition:         'attachment',
        page_size:           'letter',
        orientation:         'landscape',
        lowquality:          'false',
        debug:                true
    end
  end    
end
```

Each and everything like the wkhtml path or anything that can be taken of care of in the code is fine. The only difference I saw is in the logs i.e after this line

```
***************WICKED***************
    Rendered reports/generate_supplier_commission_pdf.html.erb within layouts/pdf_layout (5.2ms)
```

The following line is not present on server logs.

```
"***************[\"/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf\", \"-q\", \"--orientation\", \"landscape\", \"--page-size\", \"letter\", \"--encoding\", \"UTF8\", \"--lowquality\", \"--print-media-type\", \"file:///tmp/wicked_pdf20160903-24256-1v1ay70.html\", \"/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20160903-24256-1da8k68.pdf\"]***************"
```

I will be really grateful if someone could point out what is going wrong in this case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by commenting this line in my `config/environments/production.rb`

```
# config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

and adding this line in it's place:

```
config.assets.compress = true
```